# Why does this regular expression match as few characters as possible?

Tags: regex

I can match an 'a' followed by at least 2 other characters before another 'a' with the following regular expression.

```
a.{2,}?a
```

Interestingly, including the question mark makes the regex match the instance with the fewest number of middle characters possible, so for instance, given the following string,

```
abbabbbba
```

the regex will match the leftmost abba instead of the whole string. Why does including the question mark cause the regex to match the instance with the fewest number of middle characters?

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark after a quantifier makes the quantifier lazy. It is a basic feature of regex, you need to learn more about it.

a link: [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info)

(?:or|and) the one in hwnd comment.

Comment: I wouldn't call something not available in BRE (or even ERE) a "basic" feature. Support for lazy matching is very much an extension not present in early regex syntax, albeit a popular one these days.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Reassure me, you will not do nightmare tonight?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'm not sleeping like you, in your ivory tower from 70s (far from the reality). "Lazy" as "non-greedy", is the current word used by all for this kind of quantifier. Another thing that is "popular" one these days.

Comment: "Non-greedy" was the word used in the literature through the late 90s. Anyhow, Thompson NFAs are still king for high-performance regular expression matching, meaning late-60s remains state of the art even today. :)

Answer (score 1):

`?` implies a lazy match

here is the details of your regex

/a.{2,}?a/

`a` matches the character a literally (case sensitive)

`.` matches any character (except newline)

`{2,}` Quantifier: Between 2 and unlimited times

`?` as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

`a` matches the character a literally (case sensitive)